# Change CSS through div and not class

Tags: html, css

I'm using an app that allow me to change only the CSS of a webpage.

The devs create a step_btn class for 2 distinct buttons (previous and next button) and i want to change the CSS of each button separately.

I tried to make the changes through the div id but nothing happened...

Here is the page code :

```
<div id="j_id0:j_id73" class="navbuttonsContainer">
   <div id="j_id0:j_id74"    style="height:35px;overflow:visible;position:relative;" class="rowElem">
      <div id="j_id0:j_id78" class="btnWrapper">
         <a class="step_btn" onclick="saveAndGoTo('next')" title="Next Page">
            <span id="j_id0:nextBtn">Next Page</span>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id="j_id0:j_id81"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here are my tries :

```
#j_id0:j_id78
div#j_id0:j_id78 {}
div#j_id0:j_id78 .step_btn {}
```

Is it my tries that failed or the webpage doesn't interpret my code correctly ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @MelanciaUK - it's part of the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an attribute selector to enclose the `id` as a string, e.g.

```
[id="j_id0:j_id78"] .step_btn { ... }
```

In fact using the `id` selector — like for `#j_id0:j_id78` — the parser would consider `j_id0` as the `id` and `:j_id78` as a pseudoselector

Note: no need to specify the `div` element in front of the attribute, since the `id` should be unique in the page.

Comment: Even better, don't use this kind of `id` in your page.

Comment: Right, but sometimes it's not possible to have the full control of the markup @MelanciaUK

Comment: @MelanciaUK - it appears that it was not by choice of the OP.

Comment: Agreed. It was more like a side note.

Comment: No need for an attribute selector here, just escape the colon with a backslash: `#j_id0\:j_id78`.